# JavaScript Split Function with RegExp Regular Expression (/\s*$/)

Tags: javascript, regex

it is about splitting at the string end with a regexp as splitter

```js
console.log('ab '.split(/\s*$/));
```

> outputs :  ['ab', '']

but if I remove the ending space

```js
console.log('ab'.split(/\s*$/))
```

> outputs :  ['ab']

why the second one does not have a '' in the output ?

Comment: Because there is no `' '` in second input

Comment: `.split()` with regular expression arguments has always been kind-of weird. I suspect that the answer is simply that when the split regex matches a zero-length string, it's not included in the result. This might vary between implementations.

Comment: @Pointy But try splitting on a lookahead, e.g. `(?=.)`, which results in `[a, b]`.  A lookahead is also zero width, yet JS does in fact split on it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this would be illustrative of my characterization of the process as being "kind-of weird".

Comment: @Pointy The correct answer might sadly just be "because this is how they implemented it".  At least this question documents this behavior.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed, it's a fine question. Personally I've never tried to do a `.split()` with a regex because I've always assumed it would do something I didn't expect and I am very risk-averse.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that your regular expression `/\s*$/` when given the input `"ab"` is actually equivalent to `/$/`, since the `*` quantifier matches between **zero** and unlimited times.

So this regular expression will only match the empty string at the end of lines in your input, as can be seen with this multiline version:

```js
const input = `abc
def
ghi`;

// this will preserve the `\n` new line characters, because we split on the empty `/$/`
console.log(input.split(/\s*$/m));
```

However, the [ECMAScript definition of `String.split()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.split) has a special note regarding the case of splitting with regular expressions that may match such empty string, which reads:

> The value of separator may be an empty String, an empty regular expression, or a regular expression that can match an empty String. In this case, separator does not match the empty substring at the beginning or end of the input String, nor does it match the empty substring at the end of the previous separator match.

So this says that the first and last empty strings in our input are discarded (If it were otherwise, `"ab".split('')` would return `["", "a", "b", ""]`).

So at the end what we have can be schematized to

```
"ab"
   | // should split here
["ab", ""]
   // but we have to discard first and last empty strings
["ab"]
```

And you can see that the same would happen with `/^/` regex

```js
console.log("ab".split(/^/))
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` 
converts a string into an array of substrings in a new array. For example-

```
"ab cd".split(" ")
```

result: `["ab", "cd"]`

it splits where there is a white space `" "`. but if there is no white space it will create array contains main string. For example-

```
"abcd".split(" ")
```

result: `["abcd"]`

Now come to the part of regexp.

The `\s` is used to find a whitespace character.

`'ab '.split(/\s/)` results `["ab", ""]` and
`'ab'.split(/\s/)` results `["ab"]`

First string contains one white space, it seperates the string into two substring, but second string contains no whitespace, so it creates no substring.

The `n*` matches any string that contains zero or more occurrences of n.

so, `\s*` matches any string that contains zero or more whitespace character.

`'ab '.split(/\s*/)` results `["a", "b", ""]` and
`'ab'.split(/\s*/)` results `["a", "b"]`

Since First string contains one whitespace and one zero whitespace (total two), it splits the string into three substring. but Second String contains only one zero white space, so it creates two substring.

The `n$` quantifier matches any string with n at the end of it.

so `\s*$` matches string  any string that at least one whitespace. Because it will match only at the end of whitespace, if there is no whitespace, there will no end. so, it will not match.

`'ab '.split(/\s*$/)` results `["ab", ""]` and
`'ab'.split(/\s*$/)` results `["ab"]`

As first string contains one white space, it split the string into two substring, but because of not having any whitespace in second string, it will create no substring.

In short `(/\s*$/)` pattern searching for any whitespace at the end of the  whitespace. When you use `split(/\s*$/)`, it will only split when the pattern matches.

Comment: Actually, the regex does match something here, it will be exactly the same as (`/$/`) though, since as you said correctly _`n*`matches any string that contains __zero__ or more occurrences of n._

Comment: yes, it will match something when it is only (/\s*/). Because it occurs when zero or more whitespace is present. But when it is (/\s*$/), it will match only at the end or whitespace, if there is no whitespace, there will no end. so, it will not match

Comment: `"ab".match(/\s*$/)` or even `"ab".replace(/\s*$/, "hum hello")`

Comment: "ab".match(/\s*$/)  does match end of the string, as Kaiido mentioned.